# set the focus of a popup window every time

Tags: javascript, popup

I have two pages one.html and two.html

I am opening a new window using following code

```
//here popup is a global variable
popup=window.open('two.html','two');
```

for the first time a popup window open successfully and get the focus but 
if I try to open it again without closing already opened popup then two.html is not getting focus for the second time.

note: I have set popup window's name as 'two'

Answer (score 13):

You can use the `focus` function, as used below:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}

      if (!newwindow.closed) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

// -->
</script>
```

Comment: @hunt: nor Google Chrome.  Focusing the window this way isn't cross browser compatible.

Comment: Well it's "compatible" in that it won't hurt anything to try, but Firefox, Chrome, and Safari won't obey the request. Firefox can be configured by its user to allow `focus()` requests like that to work, but I think Chrome and Safari always ignore it. There's no way to force those browsers to pay attention. (In fact Safari is *really* serious about it: http://whatsthepointy.blogspot.com )

Comment: using window.open('two.html','two') with or without focus in chrome wont make a difference as there built to open in a net TAB, not window.

Answer (score 9):

```
focusedWindow = window.open('two.html','two').focus();
```

Directly append the focus() to the window.open protoype

Comment: opened windows are focused by default, the focus shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 6):

My empiric solution that always works:

```
setTimeout('detail.focus()', 1);
```

Appending `.focus()` right after open does not always work, nor calling a `.focus()` without setTimeout.

I know it's ugly (wanted to get rid of it right now, after some years, with no success), and I do not know the exact reasons why and how, but it works.

Comment: I fixed my firefox issue by doing setTimeout(function(){window.open(...)},1)

Comment: as I understand, setTimeout will trigger it's script after the last line of current script is finished executing, but it will not work in multythreading scripts, because the timed script will run on time...

Answer (score 3):

You can close the popup before you open it if you check to see if the popup is already open when you call the function.

```
var popup;
​function openPop() { 
    if ("close" in popup) popup.close();
    popup = window.open("http://stackoverflow.com", "test", "width=200, height=200");​​​​​​​​
}
```

​This will ensure the popup always appears on top.

Comment: well this code will close my previously opened window , and opens it another. i don't want to close my previous window

Comment: @hunt: Like I said in my comment on [pranay_stacker's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965754/set-the-focus-of-a-popup-window-everytime/2965817#2965817), the focus method will not work cross browser for popup windows.  I'm fairly sure that there's no other way to refocus the window.

Comment: you need to initialize the popup variable with an empty object for this solution to work properly

Answer (score 2):

```
var win = window.open('two.html','two');
win.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].focus(); //focus the body rather than the window.
```

Comment: This approach worked for me tested in Chrome48, FF42 and IE11.

Comment: Didn't work for me. It opens "two.html" in my first tab where I call this code. And yes, I changed the var name of `window`. I could fix this behavior by calling the second line a bit later via setTimeout, but then it didn't focus the body in i.e. Edge either.

Answer (score 1):

Check your Firefox 2 settings at

1. Go to  Tools -> Options -> Content
2. Make sure "Enable JavaScript" is turned on.
3. Next to "Enable JavaScript", click the "Advanced" button.
4. Make sure that there is a check-mark in the box 
      [x]  Raise or lower windows

If the setting "Raise or lower windows" is turned off, then 
this disables the window.focus() method.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer for myself that works. In the html of the popup body, add to the body tag onload="this.window.focus()". Even if you minimize the window, it pops back up front and center. Be sure and name the window in your execution script window.open('url','some name','vars'); Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately some modern browsers still don't support focusing tabs, see [this Firefox bug entry](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416771), for example.

However, the following code is working well for me. As a workaround, it reopens a window/tab if it cannot be focussed:

```
  var win = window.open("two.html", "two")
  win.focus();
  setTimeout(function() {
    if(document.hasFocus()) {
      win.close();
      window.open("two.html", "two")
    }
  }, 1);
```

In the first line it opens the window and tries to focus it using the second line. If a window with the name `two` is already there, no new window/tab is opened, but it's reused.

The trick now is, that we check if the current window still has focus using `document.hasFocus()`. If so, we close the window and reopen it. This is only for browsers which don't support focusing the tab which is to be reused directly. Currently, this is the case for FF and IE/MS Edge. Chrome works well.

However, directly after using `window.open`, `document.hasFocus()` always returns true (so said, also in Chrome). The workaround is to use `setTimeout` one ms later.

Answer (score 1):

just add .focus() to the window.open line
`window.open('two.html','two').focus()`

I did have same problem and this seems to work in both Firefox and Chromium web browsers.
In my web [thaiiceland.com](https://thaiiceland.com) I noticed that if the popup was open, the focus didn't go on the popup and you feel nothing happen when you click on that link. So I search and after try to just add .focus() in the end of the window.open line it works.

```
<a href="currency.html" onclick="javascript:void window.open('currency.html','thaiice02','width=900,height=560,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=80,left=150').focus();return false;">Curency converter - แปลงสกุลเงิน</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function () { 
  window.open('PageName', '', 'height=560,width=1120,resizable=no,left=100,top=50,screenX=100,screenY=50'); 
}, 100);
```

-> This code is use for giving focus on newly open window.
-> Put it in javascript.('setTimeout is inbuilt function of javascript')
-> Many time happen that when popup window is opened, it will go behind the old window, So above is very useful to focus for new window.

Answer (score 0):

It is a one liner solution, use focus on your pop up var:

```
popup=window.open('two.html','two');
popup.focus();
```

This will always open your pop up window even if it is not closed.