# Firefox loses focus if the same tab is opened multiple times

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-events, window.open

I'm encountering a different behavior in Firefox and IE than in Google Chrome.
I've button with event `onClick`.

This event fires a `window.open("url", "name")` which is opening a new tab in the browser and giving the focus on it. Which is exactly what I want.

But if I go back to my first tab and click again on the button, the second window is being refreshed but the focus stays on the first window.

If I do the same in Google Chrome, the focus goes all the time to the new window.

See the code below for an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="mydiv" style="width:100px; height:200px;"></div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
          $('#mydiv').css('background-color', 'red');
          $('#mydiv').click(function() {
             window.open('http://google.fr', 'mywindowname')
          });
      });
    </script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot fix this with code.  How a browser handles new windows is a characteristic of the browser, not something controlled through `javascript`.  Each client's settings may be different and may not support your intentions.

Also see this related article: [set the focus of a popup window everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965754/set-the-focus-of-a-popup-window-everytime)

Some of the answers go on to say that it is not well supported and for the same reason I explain above.