# Webhelp window in Robohelp doesn't get focused

Tags: javascript, adobe, robohelp

I am using trail version of `RoboHelp 2015`, I have few issues when I open `web-help` popups from the links in webpage.

I click on help on page, which opens a `web-help` as a popup or new tab with focus on it. In the a scenario I keep that window open and navigate back to main website and do some work and in some other page I click help which loads respective content to that window but doesn't get focused.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you have integrated webhelp in your web pages.
If you are using RoboHelp_CSH.js then you may need to modify 
   window.open(... , "__webCshStub", sParam); 
to
   window.open(... , "__webCshStub", sParam).focus();

or something like as suggested in [set the focus of a popup window everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965754/set-the-focus-of-a-popup-window-everytime)

You can also log a case @ https://helpx.adobe.com/tech-comm-suite/customer-support.html

Thanks
Amit Jha