# How to return focus on parent window from a pop window while loading first time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on a website. Where while loading website first time opening index page with one pop window. First my problem is I want to minimize this pop window automatically while loading first time and focus return to website without any click in website.

Here is my code in index page I write this function:

```
myFunction();
 function myFunction() {
   //var myWindow = window.open("music.php", "", "width=320,height=60");

   var myWindow = window.open("music.php", "", "directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=-100000000, top=100000, width=320, height=1, display=none","visibility=hidden");
    //myWindow.moveTo(0, 0);
}
```

And pop window having page extension `music.php` which should be minimize automatically and focus return to index page without any click on website.

I have already try with [set the focus of a popup window to website everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965754/set-the-focus-of-a-popup-window-everytime) , but it was also not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, The window object has an opener property as well.
When we open the browser, that property is null, and when we open a popup , it points to the window the popup has been opened through.

I think something like this should suffice.

```
myFunction();
 function myFunction() {

   var myWindow = window.open("music.php", "", "directories=0,titlebar=0,toolbar=0,location=0,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=-100000000, top=100000, width=320, height=1, display=none","visibility=hidden");

   myWindow.opener.focus()   // can also do window.focus()

}
```

The execution of JS should not stop, but if it does, you have to add the focus code to your child page/popup page.(Depending on varying browsers)

like

**popupHTMLJS.js**

```
focusParent();
function focusParent(){
    parent = window.opener;
    parent.focus()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i tried with this opner property also while loading first time index page trigger this function call pop window page but if we use give child and parent two page and try to use focus for parent still focus is going on pop window

Comment: Check my site here is url (http://bhairavijaikishan.com) here one popup window is opening that i want to minimize automatically and run in background play