# Open new browser window with "Always on top"

Tags: html

I know that this is not a good practice :-) but I have a request to open a new browser window which is "always on top". It is a small notification/statistics window and not an ad pop up.

I tried with open a new window from main page:

```
<a href="okence.html"  
   onclick="window.open('okence.html', 'newwindow', 'width=400,height=320'); return false;"
>Click</a>
```

The new html file has:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            onblur = function() {
                setTimeout('self.focus()', 100);
            }
        </script>

        Test
    </body>
</html>
```

The new window opens, but doesn't have "always on top". Is there any other way? Or maybe browsers don't allow that?

I have tried some suggestions (also [set the focus of a popup window every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965754/set-the-focus-of-a-popup-window-every-time)) but none of them works. New (small) window is opened, but if I click somewhere outside, its gone behind. I want a classic "Always on top" feature, where window stays on screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [set the focus of a popup window every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965754/set-the-focus-of-a-popup-window-every-time)

Comment: I'm happy this isn't possible.

Comment: have you found a solution for this

Comment: No. We create an application instead. It isn't so convinient, but ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make my page appear at the top when it gets refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422210/make-my-page-appear-at-the-top-when-it-gets-refresh)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. It's a huge security issue if sites could do this! Scammy web sites could keep visitors from de-focusing the window.

Think about it:

What if your e-mail program stuck a pop-up in your face every time you received a new e-mail message? If you don't like it, you will want to minimize it or at least hide it behind some other window. Problem is, what if you can't hide it behind another window? This ruins user experience.

Instead, try:

- flashing the title bar (like Gmail when a new Hangouts message is received: title bar flashes from "Gmail - Inbox" to "<name> says..."). Like this: 
  [image: Finished Demo]
  The code is below. Make sure to stop running the snippet when you're done by clicking `Hide Results` to make sure the snippet stops draining your RAM by flashing a title.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var title = document.getElementById('title');
  if (title.innerHTML === "Original Title") {
    title.innerHTML = "New Notification!";
  } else {
    title.innerHTML = "Original Title";
  }
},1000)
```

```html
<p id="title">Original Title</p>
<small>Because Stack Snippets don't have &lt;title> support, I used a p element there. In real development, replace &lt;p> with &lt;title>.</small>
```

- adding a red dot to the favicon, so the user can see there is a notification when they glance on the tab bar. Code:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var flash = document.getElementById('flash');
  if (flash.src == "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAgklEQVQ4Ed2RSw6AMAhEOYhLT+7p3HiGGjRTp0OxJrpyQeiH9yhqtqzlVaSwWTGOrFEQAOoBfqfnzUGvIAAiqYInMGRc+42AjegyymCOF2AzgvgezF8EPhtm4jllvU1zQVx/D0U3AkCaz+8HgedEoiDvrT4FIpeIiAFdR4GKSMgwGu91q05tY4o1SAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==") {
    document.getElementById('flash').src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAdklEQVQ4Ed2RQQ6AMAgE+f8zfJ2/qME4zbqV1MSePDQU2FlKGrHt7dMp4YgWeqpBgwHQE5A9r98KT4IBMJNu8AbGTLVrDNSRKbMIc76AZAZpH+YvBrkbO+me1V21a76RSepMzaNr+gsQpsBF2SvrgB4BiN6/8gPOhlAtW0V8NgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
  } else {
    flash.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAgklEQVQ4Ed2RSw6AMAhEOYhLT+7p3HiGGjRTp0OxJrpyQeiH9yhqtqzlVaSwWTGOrFEQAOoBfqfnzUGvIAAiqYInMGRc+42AjegyymCOF2AzgvgezF8EPhtm4jllvU1zQVx/D0U3AkCaz+8HgedEoiDvrT4FIpeIiAFdR4GKSMgwGu91q05tY4o1SAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==";
  }
},1000);
```

```html
<small>Once again, stack snippets does not support favicons. In real development, change img to link.</small>
<img rel="icon" type="image/png"  id="flash" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAgklEQVQ4Ed2RSw6AMAhEOYhLT+7p3HiGGjRTp0OxJrpyQeiH9yhqtqzlVaSwWTGOrFEQAOoBfqfnzUGvIAAiqYInMGRc+42AjegyymCOF2AzgvgezF8EPhtm4jllvU1zQVx/D0U3AkCaz+8HgedEoiDvrT4FIpeIiAFdR4GKSMgwGu91q05tY4o1SAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAgklEQVQ4Ed2RSw6AMAhEOYhLT+7p3HiGGjRTp0OxJrpyQeiH9yhqtqzlVaSwWTGOrFEQAOoBfqfnzUGvIAAiqYInMGRc+42AjegyymCOF2AzgvgezF8EPhtm4jllvU1zQVx/D0U3AkCaz+8HgedEoiDvrT4FIpeIiAFdR4GKSMgwGu91q05tY4o1SAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

What to avoid:

- playing a huge sound when a new notification arrives
- trying to force user activation (fortunately, most browsers block this)
- lastly, opening a popup window.

So popups are not such of a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. To be honest, in last years we change the behaviour and find a different approach.