# make my page appear at the top when it gets refresh

Tags: html, css

Im trying to learn code and make a page for myself, and IM looking for a code or  language where belongs the code to make my page appear at the top when it gets refresh instead of staying in place when its done. I have seeing java or jquery code to do so but is there any html or css code that does the trick? trying my first question, to to all this.

Comment: What do you mean by "appear at the top"? and "staying in place when it's done"? Please provide some clarification or there are good chances that this question will be closed or deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this. When the page is fully loaded, the page will appear at the top. This needs [JQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js).

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```